# Поворот картинки на определенный угол в Javascript (без CSS3)

Tags: html, css, javascript

Как повернуть картинку img или div с background-image на определенный угол?

Comment: С использованием CSS3 или без?

Comment: Нет, без css3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего использовать плагин JQuery: [jQueryRotate](http://wilq32.adobeair.pl/jQueryRotate/Wilq32.jQueryRotate.html). Если нужно на чистом Javascript и только для IE, - [DXImageTransform](http://elouai.com/javascript/javascript-image-rotate.php).

Comment: там же canvas используется(

Comment: А... нет, ошибся.